# Python numpy.nan and logical functions: wrong results

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, boolean, nan

I get some surprising results when trying to evaluate
logical expressions on data that might contain `nan` values (as defined in numpy).

I would like to understand why this results arise
and how to implement the correct way.

What I don't understand is why these expressions evaluate to the value they do:

```
from numpy import nan

nan and True
>>> True
# this is wrong.. I would expect to evaluate to nan

True and nan
>>> nan
# OK

nan and False
>>> False
# OK regardless the value of the first element 
# the expression should evaluate to False

False and nan
>>> False
#ok
```

Similarly for `or`:

```
True or nan
>>> True #OK

nan or True
>>> nan #wrong the expression is True

False or nan
>>> nan #OK

nan or False
>>> nan #OK
```

How can I implement (in an efficient way) the correct boolean functions, handling also `nan` values?

Comment: On a side note, what you're wanting doesn't make much sense with the way `numpy` currently works. `NaN` is a purely floating-point value.  Boolean arrays can't hold `NaN`s.  Therefore, having a logical comparison return `NaN` would break essentially everything.  To get around that, a special `np.na` (different from `np.nan`) value was introduced, and has been temporarily removed.  It does what you're wanting: https://github.com/numpy/numpy.org/blob/master/NA-overview.rst

Comment: See [Why do “Not a Number” values equal True when cast as boolean in Python/Numpy?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15686318/222914)

Comment: @JoeKington thanks for the comment. It is good to know, unfortunately in this case I have to use results from a third-party module that return nan values, so I don't have much choices.

Comment: This is just totally counterintuitive and leads to unexpected results... What a nuisance

Comment: Fwiw in my case I fugded it with `df['value'].shift(-1).fillna(100)<0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use predicates from the `numpy` namespace:

```
>>> np.logical_and(True, np.nan), np.logical_and(False, np.nan)
(True, False)
>>> np.logical_and(np.nan, True), np.logical_and(np.nan, False)
(True, False)
>>>
>>> np.logical_or(True, np.nan), np.logical_or(False, np.nan)
(True, True)
>>> np.logical_or(np.nan, True), np.logical_or(np.nan, False)
(True, True)
```

EDIT: The built-in boolean operators are slightly different. [From the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short%20circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not) :
`x and y` is equivalent to `if x is false, then x, else y`. So, if the first argument evaluates to `False`, they return it (*not* its boolean equivalent, as it were). Therefore:

```
>>> (None and True) is None
True
>>> [] and True
[]
>>> [] and False
[]
>>>
```

etc

Comment: on what grounds do you expect it to?

Comment: because the "and" requires both values to be true.. if one of them is unknown you simply can't decide the value.. and the result is unknown as well..

Comment: `np.bool(np.nan)` evaluates to `True`. From that point on, it's all consistent.

Comment: if you want to have a type with *three values*, true, false and 'don't know', have a look at `boost::tribool`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/tribool.html

Comment: boost are not cpp libraries? In any way it is quite easy.. an `and` can be redefined as a min function providing keys -1,0,1 for 0, nan and 1 respectively. using the same keys  `or` is implemented as max.

Comment: yes, boost is cpp. Only mentioned it to draw your attention to the fact that what you wanted a sort of a three-state boolean. In fact, the behavior you're seeing with python predicates is clearly articulated in the docs, am editing it into the answer.

Comment: `np.logical_and` is a function whose output is always a BOOLEAN VALUE (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) . Whereas , the output of python expressions containing BOOLEAN operators need not be a BOOLEAN OUTPUT.

Answer (score 0):

While evaluating logical expressions containing `and`, we have to evaluate the expressions that are present on both sides of the `and` operator. Whereas for `or` operator, if the first expression is True, then there is no need to check for the correctness of the second expression

E.g., While evaluating the expression `2>2 and 3==3` , first we should check whether the first expression `2>2` is True or not. If this first expression is False, then there is no need to check the second expression because of the `AND` operator and the result of such an expression will be FALSE as the first expression is FALSE. Whereas if the expression has been `2==2 AND 3==3` , then since the first expression `2==2` is True, then we need not check the correctness of the second expression and since here the second expression is also True, we get TRUE as the output.

In `nan and True`, since `nan` is True and because of `AND` operator, python will now evaluate the second expression and returns the value of second expression. So, here you will get `TRUE` as output. Same logic when applied to `True and nan`, you can expect `nan` as the output.

In `OR` operator, it is sufficient enough if we look at the first expression, hence "`True or nan` will return True

Comment: ..this explains the results that I would expect to get.. e.g. nan or True should return True (if nan is treated as True), and not nan..

Comment: since nan is True, python will return nan itself (not True) e.g., "2 or True" will return 2 (since 2 is True) and likewise "0 or 3" will return 3 (since 0 is considered as False). "2 and 3" will return 3 . "2 and True" will return True

Comment: both `or` and `and` short-circuit: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short%20circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not

Comment: @Nakamura both nan == True and nan is True evaluate to False though.. so do nan == False and nan is False. nan is neither False nor True, that's why I think the behaviour is wrong.

Comment: First, the output of a python expression containing boolean operators like `and`,`or` need not be a boolean (`True` or `False`) and this is nicely mentioned in the link pointed by @Zhenya . E.g., the output of the expression `[] or 2` will be `2` .Secondly, numpy.nan refers to "Not A Number" ( http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) and thus it would not be equal to either boolean True or boolean False operator. From the first point, we can infer that the output of the python expression `nan and True` will be `True` where as the output of `nan and 2` will be `2'