# Comparing logical values to NaN in pandas/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to do an element-wise OR operation on two pandas Series of boolean values. `np.nan`s are also included.

I have tried three approaches and realized that the expression "`np.nan` or `False`" can be evaluted to `True`, `False`, and `np.nan` depending on the approach.

These are my example Series:

```
series_1 = pd.Series([True, False, np.nan])
series_2 = pd.Series([False, False, False])
```

#### Approach #1

Using the `|` operator of pandas:

```
In [5]: series_1 | series_2
Out[5]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

#### Approach #2

Using the `logical_or` function from numpy:

```
In [6]: np.logical_or(series_1, series_2)
Out[6]: 
0     True
1    False
2      NaN
dtype: object
```

#### Approach #3

I define a vectorized version of `logical_or` which is supposed to be evaluated row-by-row over the arrays:

```
@np.vectorize
def vectorized_or(a, b):
   return np.logical_or(a, b)
```

I use `vectorized_or` on the two series and convert its output (which is a numpy array) into a pandas Series:

```
In [8]:  pd.Series(vectorized_or(series_1, series_2))
Out[8]: 
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

#### Question

I am wondering about the reasons for these results.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17274707/6295616) explains `np.logical_or` and says `np.logical_or(np.nan, False)` is be `True` but why does this only works when vectorized and not in Approach #2? And how can the results of Approach #1 be explained?

Comment: [This page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#basics-stats) in the docs explains that the default behaviour of these pandas functions is set to skip NaNs in the data

Comment: Does a boolean series even support `np.nan`? What about `pd.NA` rather?

Comment: @Peter9192 Link has moved: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html

Answer (score 5):

first difference : `|` is `np.bitwise_or`. it explains the difference between #1 and #2.

Second difference : since series_1.dtype if `object` (non homogeneous data), operations  are done  row by row in the two first cases.

When using vectorize  ( #3):

> The data type of the output of `vectorized` is determined by calling
> the function with the first element of the input.  This can be avoided
> by specifying the `otypes` argument.

For vectorized operations, you quit the object mode. data are first converted  according to first element (bool here,  `bool(nan)` is `True`) and the operations are done after.

Comment: I understand the effect of vectorization now. But you say that in the second case the operations are done row by row. The way I see is that the last operation is `np.logical_or(np.nan, False)`, which is `True`, so why is the last element of the second result a `NaN`?

Comment: Your other remark about `|` being `np.bitwise_or` is helpful, although using `np.bitwise_or` directly with the two Series gives a TypeError, so they are not completely the same.