# pandas column selection: non commutative bitwise OR when selecting on str and NaN

Tags: python, pandas

#### Introduction:

Given a dataframe, I though that the following were True:

```
df[(condition_1) | (condition_2)] <=> df[(condition_2) | (condition_1)]
```

as in

```
df[(df.col1==1) | (df.col1==2)] <=> df[(df.col1==2) | (df.col1==1)]
```

#### Problem:

But it turns out that it fails in the following situation, where it involves `NaN` which is probably the reason why it fails:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, "abc", 2], ["abc", 2, 3], [np.nan, 5,6], [8,9,10]], columns=["A", "B", "C"])
df
     A    B   C
0  NaN  abc   2
1  abc    2   3
2  NaN    5   6
3    8    9  10
```

The following works as expected:

```
df[(df.A.isnull()) | (df.A.str.startswith("a"))]
     A    B  C
0  NaN  abc  2
1  abc    2  3
2  NaN    5  6
```

But if I commute the elements, I get a different result:

```
df[(df.A.str.startswith("a")) | (df.A.isnull())]
     A  B  C
1  abc  2  3
```

I think that the problems comes from this condition:

```
df.A.str.startswith("a")
0     NaN
1    True
2     NaN
3     NaN
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Where I have `NaN` instead of `False`.

#### Questions:

- Is this behavior expected? Is it a bug ? Because it can lead *to potential loss of data* if one is not expecting this kind of behavior.
- Why it behaves like this (in a non commutative way) ?

---

#### More details:

More precisely, let's `C1 = (df.A.str.startswith("a"))` and `C2 = (df.A.isnull())`:

with:

```
  C1     C2
 NaN   True
True  False
 NaN   True
 NaN  False
```

We have:

```
C1 | C2
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Here C2 is not evaluated, and NaN becomes False.

And here:

```
C2 | C1
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Where NaN is False (it returns all False with an `&`) but both conditions are evaluated.

Clearly: `C1 | C2 != C2 | C1`

I wouldn't mind that `NaN` produce weird results as long as the commutativity is preserved, but here there is one condition that is not evaluated.

Actually the NaN in the input isn't the problem, because you have the same problem on column `B`:

```
(df.B.str.startswith("a")) | (df.B==2) != (df.B==2) | (df.B.str.startswith("a"))
```

It's because applying `str` method on other objects returns `NaN`*, which if evaluated first prevents the second condition to be evaluated. So the main problem remains.

*(can be chosen with `str.startswith("a", na=False)` as @ayhan noticed)

Comment: You can often get weird behavior with NaNs.  You should basically always expect weird behavior with NaNs.  It's probably not a good idea to use `str` operations if you're not already sure all the values are strings.

Comment: These methods generally have `na` parameter where you can specify how to treat NaNs. `df.A.str.startswith("a", na=False)` returns False when the value is NaN, for example.

Comment: @ayhan if you make an answer with this, it would be nice ! But it doesn't explain why it's not commutative, if it fails it both situations I would understand better.

Comment: I also don't think that answers the question completely and it's a little bit early. Someone might explain that behavior.

Comment: @ayhan you're right that it would not be a complete answer. Let's wait then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, I am rather sure that this is a bug in `pandas`. I was not able to find the specific reason in their code but my conclusion is that either you should be forbidden to do the comparison at all or there is a bug in evaluating the `|` expression. You can reproduce the problem with a very simple example, namely:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series(np.nan)
b = pd.Series(True)

print( a | b )  # Gives False
print( b | a )  # Gives True
```

The second result is obviously the correct one. I can only guess the reason, why the first one fails, due to my lack of understanding `pandas` code base. So if I am mistaken, please correct me or if you feel this is not enough of an answer, please let me know.

Generally, `np.nan` is treated as `True` all throughout python, as you can easily check:

```
import numpy as np
if np.nan:
    print("I am True")
```

This is valid in `numpy` and even `pandas` as well, as you can see by doing:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
if np.all(np.array([np.nan])):
    print("I am True in numpy")
if pd.Series(np.nan).astype("bool").bool():
    print("and in pandas")
```

or by simply doing `pd.Series([np.nan]).astype("bool")`.

So far everything is consistent. The problem now arises when you do `|` with a `Series` containing `NaN`s. There are multiple other people with similar problems, as for example in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131462/comparing-logical-values-to-nan-in-pandas-numpy) or that [blog post](https://unsupervised.blogs.balabit.com/2016/05/comparing-logical-arrays-in-numpypandas/) (which is for an older version, though). And none give a satisfactory answer to the problem. The only answer to the linked question actually gives no good reason, as `|` does not even behave the same way as it would for `numpy` arrays containing the same information. For numpy, `np.array(np.nan) | np.array(True)` and `np.array(np.nan) | np.array(1.0)` actually give a `TypeError` as `np.bitwise_or` is not able to work on floats.

Due to the inconsistent behavior and the lack of any documentation on this, I can only conclude that this is a bug. As a workaround you can fall back to the solution proposed by @ayhan and use the `na` parameter, if that exists for all functions that you need. You could also use `.astype("bool")` on the `Series`/`Dataframe` that you want to compare. Note however, that this will convert `NaN` to `True` as this is the usual `python` convention (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15686477/6614295) for example). If you want to avoid that, you can use `.fillna(False).astype("bool")`, which I found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pydata/U7gQyI_gLMc). Generally, one should probably file a bug report with pandas, as this behavior is obviously inconsistent!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was kind of thinking that it was a bug too, but unsure. I'm still waiting a bit for others to comment or answer before filling an issue if no one else fills one before.

Comment: @jeanrjc No problem. Sorry for not being able to give you a real reason for the behavior. I would have have put everything in a comment, but all the stuff I wanted to mention was way too much for 600 characters...

Comment: That's totally fine, I really appreciated the work you've done !

Comment: Opened an issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/51267