# Broken symmetry of operations between Boolean pandas.Series with unequal index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

The implicit index-matching of `pandas` for operations between different `DataFrame`/`Series` is great and most of the times, it just works.

However, I've stumbled on an example that does not work as expected:

```
import pandas as pd # 0.21.0
import numpy as np # 1.13.3
x = pd.Series([True, False, True, True], index = range(4))
y = pd.Series([False, True, True, False], index = [2,4,3,5])

# logical AND: this works, symmetric as it should be
pd.concat([x, y, x & y, y & x], keys = ['x', 'y', 'x&y', 'y&x'], axis = 1)
#        x      y    x&y    y&x
# 0   True    NaN  False  False
# 1  False    NaN  False  False
# 2   True  False  False  False
# 3   True   True   True   True
# 4    NaN   True  False  False
# 5    NaN  False  False  False

# but logical OR is not symmetric anymore (same for XOR: x^y vs. y^x)
pd.concat([x, y, x | y, y | x], keys = ['x', 'y', 'x|y', 'y|x'], axis = 1)
#        x      y    x|y    y|x
# 0   True    NaN   True  False <-- INCONSISTENT!
# 1  False    NaN  False  False
# 2   True  False   True   True
# 3   True   True   True   True
# 4    NaN   True  False   True <-- INCONSISTENT!
# 5    NaN  False  False  False
```

Researching a bit, I found two points that seem relevant:

- `bool(np.nan)` equals `True`, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15686477/2965879
- `|` is resolved to `np.bitwise_or`, rather than `np.logical_or`, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37132854/2965879

But ultimately, the kicker seems to be that pandas does casting from `nan` to `False` *at some point*. Looking at the above, it appears that this happens *after* calling  `np.bitwise_or`, while I think this should happen *before*?

In particular, using `np.logical_or` does not help because it misses the index alignment that `pandas` does, and also, I don't want `np.nan or False` to equal `True`. (In other words, the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37132854/2965879 does not help.)

**I think that if this wonderful syntactic sugar is provided, it should be as consistent as possible*, and so `|` should be symmetric**. It's really hard to debug (as happened to me) when something that's always symmetric suddenly isn't anymore.

So finally, the question: Is there any feasible workaround (e.g. overloading something) to salvage `x|y == y|x`, and ideally in such a way that (loosely speaking) `nan | True == True == True | nan` and `nan | False == False == False | nan`?

*even if De Morgan's law falls apart regardless - `~(x&y)` can not fully match `~y|~x` because the NaNs only come in at the index alignment (and so are not affected by a previous negation).

Comment: this issue seems more like a bug than something to work around, and your post is structured better as a bug report than a question. +1 but you may just want to inform the developers about this.

Comment: There was an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6528) about this. I couldn't find at the moment but I remember some SO questions on the same subject, too.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, I agree of course. I was just worried that anything regarding NaN-handling will just get pushed off to pandas 2.0 anyway (where Wes McKinney plans unified NaN-handling). I would prefer a solution before that. ;-)

Comment: @ayhan, the referenced issue leads to another one (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13896), where it is marked as a milestone for "1.0" since Oct. 2016 (so missed 0.20 and 0.21 already). Seems like it has low priority...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some exploring in pandas, I discovered that there is a function called `pandas.core.ops._bool_method_SERIES` which is one of several factory functions that wrap the boolean operators for Series objects.

```
>>> f = pandas.Series.__or__
>>> f #the actual function you call when you do x|y
<function _bool_method_SERIES.<locals>.wrapper at 0x107436bf8>
>>> f.__closure__[0].cell_contents
    #it holds a reference to the other function defined in this factory na_op
<function _bool_method_SERIES.<locals>.na_op at 0x107436b70>
>>> f.__closure__[0].cell_contents.__closure__[0].cell_contents
    #and na_op has a reference to the built-in function or_
<built-in function or_>
```

This means we could theoretically define our own method that would perform a logical or with the correct logic, first let's see what it will actually do (remember an operator function is expected to raise a TypeError if the operation can't be performed)

```
def test_logical_or(a,b):
    print("**** calling logical_or with ****")
    print(type(a), a)
    print(type(b), b)
    print("******")
    raise TypeError("my_logical_or isn't implemented")

#make the wrapper method
wrapper = pd.core.ops._bool_method_SERIES(test_logical_or, None,None)
pd.Series.logical_or = wrapper #insert method


x = pd.Series([True, False, True, True], index = range(4))
y = pd.Series([False, True, True, False], index = [2,4,3,5])

z = x.logical_or(y) #lets try it out!

print(x,y,z, sep="\n")
```

When this gets run (at least with pandas vs 0.19.1)

```
**** calling logical_or with ****
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> [True False True True nan nan]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> [False False False  True  True False]
******
**** calling logical_or with ****
<class 'bool'> True
<class 'bool'> False
******
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
```

So it looks like it tried to call our method with two numpy arrays, where for whatever reason the second one has the `nan` values already replaced with `False` but not the first one which is likely why our symmetry breaks.  and then when that failed it tried again I'd assume element-wise.

So as a bare minimum to get this working you can just explicitly check that both arguments are numpy arrays, try to convert all the `nan` entries of the first to `False` then `return np.logical_or(a,b)`.  I'm going to assume if anything else is the case we will just raise an error.

```
def my_logical_or(a,b):
    if isinstance(a, np.ndarray) and isinstance(b, np.ndarray):
        a[np.isnan(a.astype(float))] = False
        b[np.isnan(b.astype(float))] = False
        return np.logical_or(a,b)
    else:
        raise TypeError("custom logical or is only implemented for numpy arrays")

wrapper = pd.core.ops._bool_method_SERIES(my_logical_or, None,None)
pd.Series.logical_or = wrapper


x = pd.Series([True, False, True, True], index = range(4))
y = pd.Series([False, True, True, False], index = [2,4,3,5])

z = pd.concat([x, y, x.logical_or(y), y.logical_or(x)], keys = ['x', 'y', 'x|y', 'y|x'], axis = 1)
print(z)
#        x      y    x|y    y|x
# 0   True    NaN   True   True
# 1  False    NaN  False  False <-- same!
# 2   True  False   True   True
# 3   True   True   True   True
# 4    NaN   True   True   True <-- same!
# 5    NaN  False  False  False
```

So that could be your workaround, I would not recommend modifying `Series.__or__` since we don't know who else would be using it and don't want to break any code that expects the default behaviour.

---

Alternatively,  we can modify the source code at [`pandas.core.ops` line 943](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/ops.py#L943) to fill `NaN` values with False (or 0) for `self` in the same [way it does with `other`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/ops.py#L939), so we'd change the line:

```
    return filler(self._constructor(na_op(self.values, other.values),
                                    index=self.index, name=name))
```

to use `filler(self).values` instead of `self.values`:

```
    return filler(self._constructor(na_op(filler(self).values, other.values),
                                    index=self.index, name=name))
```

This also fixes the issue with `or` and `xor` not being symmetric, however, I would not recommend this since it may break other code, I personally don't have nearly enough experience with pandas to determine what this would change in different circumstances.