# Why does pandas "None | True" return False when Python "None or True" returns True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, logical-or

In pure Python, `None or True` returns `True`.
However with pandas when I'm doing a `|` between two Series containing None values, results are not as I expected:

```py
>>> df.to_dict()
{'buybox': {0: None}, 'buybox_y': {0: True}}
>>> df
    buybox  buybox_y
0   None    True

>>> df['buybox'] = (df['buybox'] | df['buybox_y'])
>>> df
    buybox  buybox_y
0   False   True
```

Expected result:

```py
>>> df
    buybox  buybox_y
0   True    True
```

I get the result I want by applying the OR operation twice, but I don't get why I should do this.

I'm not looking for a workaround (I have it by applying `df['buybox'] = (df['buybox'] | df['buybox_y'])` twice in a row) but an explanation, thus the 'why' in the title.

Comment: `|` and `or` are two entirely different operators. Note that `None | True` produces a type error.

Comment: @chepner: Yeah, but Pandas uses `|` for logical or, and we're not getting a TypeError. We're getting False somehow.

Comment: What Pandas version are you on?

Comment: Pandas doc (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) specifies that `|` is used for logical or and not bitwise or.
My pandas version is 1.2.0

Comment: `df.any(axis=1)` works somehow :-).

Comment: can you replicate on columns with dtype other than Object?

Comment: "Somehow" would appear to mean that `__or__` is implemented to convert `None` to a `bool` first. `or` isn't really a boolean operator, but it uses boolean *equivalents* to determine which argument to return.

Comment: Additional weirdness: [if you switch the argument order, you get True instead](https://ideone.com/4eJdq3)!

Comment: Also, this is likely a bug: `None` is interpreted as truthy when evaluating the or `|` and as falsey when converted to boolean. The second part is easy to verify as `df['buybox'].astype(bool)` gets to `False`.

Comment: Huh... experiment actually contradicts the Pandas documentation. The docs say Pandas logical operations on NaN always return False, but `pandas.Series([True]) | pandas.Series([nan])` has a `True` instead of `False` in the result. (Putting the NaN first gives False.)

Comment: @norok2: If `None` were treated as truthy in the `|`, then we'd get True, not False.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica no, you would get the object, not True. Compare with `1 or True -> 1`. Likely, `|` is short-circuiting and not even caring what is on the other side, as your finding of swapping the order of operands suggests.

Comment: the `'boolean'` dtype seems to have NaN treated properly.

Comment: There's a [related issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6528) on the tracker for NaN. It looks like this is just treated as known weirdness.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47659400/9067615

Comment: Note that we don't particularly deal in "why"s here. We deal in concrete, practical questions with concrete answers; a "why" doesn't always have a rationale, beyond "that scenario wasn't included during design and failed to be considered". See f/e [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170415/144918)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't see the question as that type of why. This why is more of a "This code does something else from what I would expect. What am I overlooking? Where is my mistake?" which to me seems like a very common and meaningful type of question on Stack Overflow. And pointing to how the or operators are defined in pandas, or what bug this behaviour is a consequence of (I don't know which is the case), would answer the question. The OP doesn't ask _why_ the operators are defined like that or _why_ there is a bug; only in those cases would it be a why of the type you mention.

Comment: @Jesper, I generally agree; it's that the comments asserting that there _is_ a bug were ignored / treated as nonresponsive by the OP (and the question had a bounty added with a message refocusing on the interest being an explanation rather than a workaround) that led to the above comment.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pandas `|` operator does not rely on Python [`or expression`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#or), and behaves differently.

If both operands are boolean, the result is mathematically defined, and the same for Python and Pandas.

But in your case series "buybox" is of type `object`, and "buybox_y" is `bool`. In this case Pandas `|` operator is [not commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property):

- right operand is coerced to boolean
- then `bitwise or` is attempted

  - `None | True` is invalid operation, resulting in `None`
- and result is coerced to boolean

Thus,

```py
>>> df['buybox'] | df['buybox_y']
0  False

>>> df['buybox_y'] | df['buybox']
0  True
```

For predictable results, you can clean up data, and cast to boolean type with Pandas [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) before attempting boolean operations.

Answer (score -1):

For Boolean objects (ie Py_True and Py_False), the code will enter the fast processing branch; for other objects, PyObject_IsTrue() will be used to calculate a value of type int.

During the calculation process, the PyObject_IsTrue() function will obtain the values ​​of nb_bool, mp_length, and sq_length in turn, which should correspond to the return values ​​of the two magic methods **bool**() and **len**().

Comment: This may well be true and interesting information about how `or` works in CPython , but the issue in this question is entirely different, because it's how the `|` operator between two pandas Series works, which is a completely different implementation and doesn't match either pure Python `or` or `|`.