# Logic operator for boolean indexing with np.nan in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, logical-operators

```
result=pd.Series([True,False,False]) | pd.Series([False,True,True],index=[1,2,3])
result
```

out:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

how does the Series do logical or? why the result[3] is True?

in:

```
print(pd.Series([np.nan]) | pd.Series([True]))
print('----')
print(pd.Series([True]) | pd.Series([np.nan]))
```

out:

```
0    False
dtype: bool
----------
0    True
dtype: bool
```

could someone help to explain the difference between two times logical or?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, these are two questions.

**For the first question:**

Your problem is that you're setting the index of the second series starting from `1` rather than `0` (the default).

So, while the first Series has indexes `[0, 1, 2]`, the second one has `[1, 2, 3]`.

**For the second question:**

Please refer to this answer here in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37132854/677022