# Why does pd.Series([np.nan]) | pd.Series([True]) evaluate to False?

Tags: python, pandas

Why does the following code return `False`?

```
>>> pd.Series([np.nan]) | pd.Series([True])
0    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, since the commutative yield `True`. Should open an issue in their github.

Comment: This is interesting. Note, `np.nan or True` evaluates to `nan`, basically, `nan` will propagate in your operations. What is *super* weird is that *actually* `bool(np.nan)` will be `True`, and even more strangely, `pd.Series([np.nan],dtype=np.bool)` gives you a series with a single `True`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga To make the story more interesting, `pd.NA` (as opposed to `np.nan`) does not propagate.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6528)'s a related discussion from pandas GitHub page.

Comment: Funny indeed, as np.logical_or(np.nan, True) is True.

Comment: Related thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131462/comparing-logical-values-to-nan-in-pandas-numpy

Answer (score 4):

I think this is because `np.nan` has metaclass of `float` and I guess overrides `__bool__` to be non-zero:

```
np.nan.__bool__() == True
```

In the same way:

```
>>>np.nan or None
nan
```

A solution in pandas would be:

```
pd.Series([np.nan]).fillna(False) | pd.Series([True])
```

EDIT ***

For clarity, in `pandas 0.24.1` in the method: `_bool_method_SERIES` on line `1816` of `.../pandas/core/ops.py` there is an assignment:

```
    fill_bool = lambda x: x.fillna(False).astype(bool)
```

which is where the behaviour you are describing is coming from. I.e. it's been purposefully designed so that `np.nan` is treated like a `False` value (whenever doing an **or** operation)

Comment: *"...so that `np.nan` is treated like a `False` value (whenever doing an or operation)"* - **no**, `np.nan` is not treated as something different, try yourself `np.nan or True` and you will see that the result is `np.nan`.

Comment: @MarianD - hey, I think I referenced that above; but my point is that `pandas` fills `np.nan` with `False` during `__or__` operations - hope that helps.

Comment: **1.** Sorry, you referenced nothing (no links in your answer; BTW why version 0.24.1?). **2.** If — as you states — “padnas fill `np.nan` with `False`”, why `False or True` gives `False` (as in OP example)?

Comment: BTW, you could be more specific directly in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Compare your case (with the explicit `dtype` to emphasize the inferred one):

```
In[11]: pd.Series([np.nan], dtype=float) | pd.Series([True])
```

> ```
> Out[11]: 
> 0    False
> dtype: bool
> ```

with a similar one (only `dtype` is now `bool`):

```
In[12]: pd.Series([np.nan], dtype=bool) | pd.Series([True])
```

> ```
> Out[12]: 
> 0    True
> dtype: bool
> ```

Do you see the difference?

---

**The explanation:**

1. In the first case (yours), `np.nan` propagates itself in the logical operation `or` (under the hood)

   ```
   In[13]: np.nan or True
   Out[13]: nan
   ```

   and pandas treated `np.nan` as `False` in the context of an boolean operation result.
2. In the second case the output is unambiguous, as the first series has a boolean value (`True`, as all non-zero values are considered `True`, including `np.nan`, but it doesn't matter in this case):

   ```
   In[14]: pd.Series([np.nan], dtype=bool)
   ```

   > ```
   > Out[14]: 
   > 0    True
   > dtype: bool
   > ```

   and `True or True` gives `True`, of course:

   ```
   In[15]: True or True
   Out[15]: True
   ```