# How to skip over np.nan while iterating through a dataframe for sentiment analysis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, boolean, nan, sentiment-analysis

I have a data frame with 201279 entries, the last column is labeled "text" with customer reviews. The problem is that most of them are missing values, and come up as NaN.

I read some interesting information from this question:
[Python numpy.nan and logical functions: wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273312/python-numpy-nan-and-logical-functions-wrong-results)

and I tried applying it to my problem:

```
    df1.columns

Index(['id', 'sku', 'title', 'reviewCount', 'commentCount', 'averageRating',
       'date', 'time', 'ProductName', 'CountOfBigTransactions', 'ClassID',
       'Weight', 'Width', 'Depth', 'Height', 'LifeCycleName', 'FinishName',
       'Color', 'Season', 'SizeOrUtility', 'Material', 'CountryOfOrigin',
       'Quartile', 'display-name', 'online-flag', 'long-description', 'text'],
      dtype='object')
```

I tried experimentingby doing this:
    df['firstName'][202360]== np.nan

which returns `False` but indeed that index contains an np.nan.

So I looked for an answer, read through the question I linked, and saw that

```
np.bool(df1['text'][201279])==True
```

is a true statement. I thought, okay, I can run with this.

So, here's my code so far:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import string

def remove_num_punct(aText):
    p = string.punctuation
    d = string.digits
    j = p + d
    table = str.maketrans(j, len(j)* ' ')
    return aText.translate(table)

#Process text
aList = []
for text in df1['text']:
    if np.bool(df1['text'])==True:
        aList.append(np.nan)
    else:
        b = remove_num_punct(text)
        pol = TextBlob(b).sentiment.polarity
        aList.append(pol)
```

Then I would just convert `aList` with the sentiment to `pd.DataFrame` and join it to `df1`, then impute the missing values with K-nearest neighbors.

My problem is that the little routine I made throws a value error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

So I'm not really sure what else to try. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:  I have tried this:

```
i = 0
aList = []
for txt in df1['text'].isnull():
    i += 1
    if txt == True:
        aList.append(np.nan)
```

which correctly populates the list with NaN.

But this gives me a different error:

```
i = 0
aList = []
for txt in df1['text'].isnull():
    if txt == True:
        aList.append(np.nan)
    else:
        b = remove_num_punct(df1['text'][i])
        pol = TextBlob(b).sentiment.polarity
        aList.append(pol)
        i+=1
```

`AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'translate'`

Which doesn't make sense, since if it is not NaN, then it contains text, right?

Comment: Okay I may get df.isnull() to work but it throws an error if used on an individual index of df1['text']

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [5, 6, np.NaN],
                   'born': [pd.NaT, pd.Timestamp('1939-05-27'), pd.Timestamp('1940-04-25')],
                   'name': ['Alfred', 'Batman', ''],
                   'toy': [None, 'Batmobile', 'Joker']})

df1 = df['toy']
for i in range(len(df1)):
    if not df1[i]:
        df2 = df1.drop(i)

df2
```

you can try in this way to deal the text which is null

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I had to move the `i += 1` back from the `else` indentation to the `for` indentation:

```
i = 0
aList = []
for txt in df1['text'].isnull():
    if txt == True:
        aList.append(np.nan)
    else:
        b = remove_num_punct(df1['text'][i])
        pol = TextBlob(b).sentiment.polarity
        aList.append(pol)
    i+=1
```