# How to check the presence of np.NaN and/or None in a list

Tags: python, numpy

`None` is considered as false condition. But `np.NaN` is considered as `True` when converted as `bool`.

```
any([np.nan, np.NaN, None])
#True
```

I understand, it can be caught using `np.isnan()`. If my data has combination of `np.NaN`, `None`, `np.nan`, then how can I find it if any of these is present.

Is there any simpler way to find either of them?

**EDIT:**

Expected Output:

```
func([np.nan, np.NaN, None, 2])
#True
func([np.nan, np.NaN, None,''])
#False
```

Comment: related and probable dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686318/why-do-not-a-number-values-equal-true-when-cast-as-boolean-in-python-numpy

Comment: what is the best way to know to identify `[np.nan, np.NaN, None]` as False

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15686318/4799172 but for the last part, it's a dupe

Comment: sorry what are you trying to test here? If there is `NaN` or `None`?

Comment: It should be `False`, if all the values are belonging to `[np.nan, np.NaN, None]`

Comment: You can build a mask using `np.isin(your_array, [np.nan, np.NaN, None])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another trick:

```
arr = [np.nan, None, np.nan]

[i == i if i is not None else False  for i in arr]
```

Output:

```
[False, False, False]
```

> Note: `np.nan == np.nan` returns False

Hence,

```
arr = [np.nan, None, np.nan, '']
any([i == i if i is not None and i != '' else False  for i in arr])
```

Output:

```
False
```

And,

```
arr = [np.nan, None, np.nan, 2]

any([i == i if i is not None and i != '' else False  for i in arr])
```

Output:

```
True
```

Timings:

```
%timeit any([np.nan_to_num(x) for x in arr])
```

> 241 µs ± 22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

```
%timeit any([isvalid(x) for x in arr])
```

> 20.5 µs ± 1.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

```
%timeit any([i == i if i is not None and i != '' else False  for i in arr])
```

> 2.44 µs ± 137 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Comment: Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own custom function for checking whether a number is within your valid input set, for instance:

```
def isvalid(number):
    if number is None or np.isnan(number):
        return False
    else:
        return True

any([isvalid(x) for x in data])
```

edit: I realize you probably want to check if any of them are NOT valid, you can simply negate the isvalid result to achieve that.

Comment: return the boolean, rather than True/False, e.g. `return not (number is None or np.isnan(number))`

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to convert any nan to valid numbers, in this case `0.0` :

```
In[91]:
any([np.nan_to_num(x) for x in [np.nan, np.NaN, None]])

Out[91]: False
```

[`np.nan_to_num`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html) will convert the `NaN` to `0.0`:

```
In[92]:

[np.nan_to_num(x) for x in [np.nan, np.NaN, None]]
Out[92]: [0.0, 0.0, None]
```

## EDIT

this will also handle your updated sample data:

```
In[93]:

any([np.nan_to_num(x) for x in [np.nan, np.NaN, None,'']])
Out[93]: False
```

Comment: l liked the idea of using `nan_to_num` to handle None,empty string and Nan. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Following method considers None, various NaNs and even nan as string:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> any([~np.isnan(np.float_(x)) for x in [np.nan, np.NaN, None, 'NaN', 'nan']])
False
```

Pandas has a `notna` function that works for None and various NaNs (but not NaN as a string).

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> any([pd.notna(x) for x in [np.nan, np.NaN, None, pd.NA, pd.NaT]])
False
```

Neither of these methods work though for the empty string `''`.