# How to tell if a given 2D array has null columns in python

Tags: python, numpy

### 1 Problem

I am practicing [100 Numpy exercises](https://github.com/rougier/numpy-100/blob/master/100_Numpy_exercises.md). Question 60 asks for how to tell if a given 2D array has null columns?

I am wondering whether it asks for checking a column fulled with 0 or fulled with nan?

### 2 Solutions I found

If null columns stands for column with its value all equal to `0`, this answer satisfies.

```
# Author: Warren Weckesser
Z = np.random.randint(0,3,(3,10))
print((~Z.any(axis=0)).any())
```

It uses a trick of `any()`. Noticing that if one of values in an array is not equal to 0, `np.array().any()` will return True. For instance:

```
np.array([0,-1,0]).any()
[Out]: True
```

However, if null columns stands for column with its value all equal to `nan`, then my answer satisfies.

```
Z = np.random.randint(0,3,(3,10)).astype(float)
Z[:,0] = np.nan
G = np.isnan(Z)
print((G.all(axis=0)).any())
```

### 3 Summary

What does `null` means in python? I think is means `nan`, but it conflicts with Author(Warren Weckesser)'s answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NaN` or `nan`, either way, is the same as null. Meaning that there is no data there.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534106/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-none),

> he main reason to use NaN (over None) is that it can be stored with numpy's float64 dtype, rather than the less efficient object dtype

As you can see, `None`, `np.nan` and `0` all behave slightly differently.

```
print(any(np.array([1, None]))) # True
print(all(np.array([1, None]))) # False

print(any(np.array([1, np.nan]))) # True
print(all(np.array([1, np.nan]))) # True

print(any(np.array([1, 0]))) # True
print(all(np.array([1, 0]))) # False
```

We can see that `np.nan` for some reason always evaluates to `True`.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686318/why-do-not-a-number-values-equal-true-when-cast-as-boolean-in-python-numpy), both Python and Numpy evaluate null values as `True`.

So if a truly null value was in the example, it would be evaluating as true. I think the intent of the exercise was to show use of the `any()` function and the negation with `~`. I agree, the title is a bit off, and he's actually trying to find `False` values rather than null ones. This can also be realized in that `np.random.randint(0,3,(3,10))` will only ever return an array filled with values of `0`, `1`, or `2` and never `False` or `np.nan`.