# Bool and missing values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to figure out whether or not a column in a pandas dataframe is boolean or not (and if so, if it has missing values and so on).

In order to test the function that I created I tried to create a dataframe with a boolean column with missing values. However, I would say that missing values are handled exclusively 'untyped' in python and there are some weird behaviours:

```
> boolean = pd.Series([True, False, None])
> print(boolean)

0     True
1    False
2     None
dtype: object
```

so the moment you put None into the list, it is being regarded as object because python is not able to mix the types bool and type(None)=NoneType back into bool. The same thing happens with `math.nan` and `numpy.nan`. The weirdest things happen when you try to force pandas into an area it does not want to go to :-)

```
> boolean = pd.Series([True, False, np.nan]).astype(bool)
> print(boolean)
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

So 'np.nan' is being casted to 'True'?

Questions:

1. Given a data table where one column is of type 'object' but in fact it is a boolean column with missing values: how do I figure that out? After filtering for the non-missing values it is still of type 'object'... do I need to implement a try-catch-cast of every column into every imaginable data type in order to see the true nature of columns?
2. I guess that there is a logical explanation of why np.nan is being casted to True but this is an unwanted behaviour of the software pandas/python itself, right? So should I file a bug report?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686318/why-do-not-a-number-values-equal-true-when-cast-as-boolean-in-python-numpy

Comment: but what you exactly are trying to do ? You want to cast - NaN and None to False ? If this dataframe is meant to store information about missing values - I would rather try to ensure that input is correct i.e. it's true/false, rather than cleaning dataframe afterwards

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski In this particular case (not speaking in all generality here) I want to cast boolean values to 0,1 and if there is a missing value then it should stay missing...

Comment: Ah, gotcha. How should NaN be interpreted then  - as 0/1, or as NaN ?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski The most comfortable possibility (I think) is that there should be one single object that is integrated cleanly into the typing tree of a programming language. It should be combinable with all other simple data types and "vectors" should keep their type, i.e. [True, NA, False] should still be of type boolean. Casting this to 0/1 would then result in [1, NA, 0].

Comment: new(ish) pandas *nullable boolean dtype* might work? e.g. `astype('boolean')`, not `'bool'`. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/boolean.html

Comment: In `R` `NA` is of type `logical` by default, so missing values are preserved when converted to ~ boolean type. This is very useful, for example, with observational data (usually full of gaps) when wanting to ascertain whether data points meet a condition, e.g. rainy days or hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1: I would start with combining

```
np.any(pd.isna(boolean))
```

to identify if there are any None Values in a column, and with

```
set(boolean)
```

You can identify, if there are only True, False and Nones inside. Combining with filtering (and if you prefer to also typcasting) you should be done.

Q2: see comment of @WeNYoBen

Comment: Yes, that is more or less what I have done now: first remove missing values and then do a nonsense `test = column_without_missing.map({False: False, True: True})` and if the type of test is boolean then the original type was boolean as well...

Answer (score 0):

I've hit the same problem. I came up with the following solution:

```
from pandas import Series
def is_boolean_series(col: Series):
    val = col[~col.isna()].iloc[0]
    return type(val) == bool
```