# 'NAType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, pandas

I have searched the whole of Stack Overflow and yet to see a solution to this.

Is there a way to check whether a variable/string is NAType?

**Column:**

```
DBRef('sector', 29)
DBRef('sector', 29)
DBRef('sector', 29)
DBRef('sector', 29)
DBRef('sector', 29)
DBRef('sector', 29)
<NA>
```

**Loop:**

```
for q in list:
     b = q.split("'")[2]
     newcol.append(b)
```

**Error:**

```
AttributeError: 'NAType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

**Expected:**

```
, 29)
, 29)
, 29)
, 29)
, 29)
, 29)
<NA>
```

I want to split everything that is not `<NA>`, if it is then it should do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Just because you have `pandas` tagged), if your data is in a Series/DataFrame, you can use the `str` methods to do so, which will handle the missing values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(["DBRef('sector', 29)"] * 5 + [np.nan])
print(s.str.split("'").str[-1])
```

Output:

```
0    , 29)
1    , 29)
2    , 29)
3    , 29)
4    , 29)
5      NaN
dtype: object
```

But I suppose if you were working within your loop, you could just add an `if` check:

```
import pandas as pd

for q in list:
    if not pd.isna(q):
        b = q.split("'")[2]
        newcol.append(b)
```

Using `if pd.isna()` rather than simply `if` because `np.nan` is [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686318/why-do-not-a-number-values-equal-true-when-cast-as-boolean-in-python-numpy).