# How to map NA values of the type pandas._libs.missing.NAType

Tags: python, pandas, nan

Somewhere along my workflow `NaN` values in a Pandas DataFrame (filled in using `np.Nan`) have turned into `<NA>` values. (I am still trying to figure out how this happened. Reimporting the dataset from a CSV might be responsible?) [`pandas.DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna) works fine. However [`pandas.DataFrame.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) only maps

> NA values, such as None or numpy.NaN [...] Everything else gets mapped to False values.

Is there a way to map NA values of the type `pandas._libs.missing.NAType`?

**fictitious sample**

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
        import pandas as pd

        dictionary = {'environment': ['test', 'prod', 'test', 'prod'], 
                      'event': ['add_rd', 'add_rd', 'add_env', 'add_env'], 
                      'entry': ['yes', np.NaN, 'no', np.NaN]
                     }

        df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary, columns= ['environment', 'event', 'entry'])
```

(something happes that turns `NaN` values into `<NA>` values of the type `pandas._libs.missing.NAType`)

```
In [3]: print(df)

          environment    event entry
        0        test   add_rd   yes
        1        prod   add_rd   <NA>
        2        test  add_env    no
        3        prod  add_env   <NA>
```

Expected output:

```
In [4]: df["entry"].isna()

Out[4]  0    False
        1     True
        2    False
        3     True
        Name: entry, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected ouput?

Comment: I can not share the original dataset and I am having trouble recreating the issue. Expected output would be similar to output from `.isna()`.

Comment: I ask for sample data. [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) should help.

Comment: @jezrael I understand what you are asking for. However I fail to produce sample data that behaves like my data (`<NA>` values instead of `NaN`).

Comment: added sample to question, be free change it lik eneed, add expcted ouput and your code, what you try.

Comment: hmmm, so problem is `NA` working for `dropna` but failed for `isna` in real data?

Comment: because it should working both or failed both. One reason why failed both is `NA` is string, not missing value

Comment: `isna()` fails for `<NA>` in real data. As it should according to documentation. I am asking how to map NA values of the type pandas._libs.missing.NAType. Not why `isna()` fails for `<NA>`.

Comment: hmmm, never seen before `isna` failed for `NA`, can yu show me link to docs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239271/discussion-between-marianoju-and-jezrael).

Comment: Using `pd.isna(x)` works for me. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66495146/natype-object-has-no-attribute-split)

Comment: Please update pandas to latest version - the expected output you listed is being returned in the latest version.

Comment: @Doracahl Thanks for you suggestion, I hope it helps someone else with a similiar problem, but I no longer have access to the setup involved 1 year and 10 months ago (i.e. hardware, virtual environment, data).

Answer (score 2):

You can try pd.NA if you're **pandas is updated**:

```
df["isna"] = df["entry"].apply(lambda x:True if x is pd.NA else False)
```