# How to count where column value is falsy in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

There is a dataframe with a column name `ADDRESS`:

I try to count how much rows where address is `null, false, Nan, None, empty string` and etc.

I have tried this:

```
t = len(new_dfr[new_dfr['ADDRESS'] == ''])
print(r)
```

How to do that in Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count NA values with [isna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
df['ADDRESS'].isna().sum()
```

This will count all None, NaN values, but not `False` or empty strings. You could replace `False` with `None` to cover that:

```
df['ADDRESS'].replace('', None).replace(False, None).isna().sum()
```

Comment: I don't think this counts the empty string ''

Comment: `isna` only  counts `np.NaN` and None, not empty strings. You can check the docs

Comment: correct, updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you basically want to count all the falsy values including the NaNs (note that [NaNs are considered truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686318/why-do-not-a-number-values-equal-true-when-cast-as-boolean-in-python-numpy)). In pandas terms this can be translated into

```
# (ADDRESS is NaN) OR (ADDRESS is not truthy)
(new_dfr['ADDRESS'].isna() | ~new_dfr['ADDRESS'].astype(bool)).sum()
```

Example:

```
new_dfr = pd.DataFrame({
    'ADDRESS': [np.nan, None, False, '', 0, 1, True, 'not empty']
})


>>> new_dfr
     
     ADDRESS
0        NaN
1       None
2      False
3           
4          0
5          1
6       True
7  not empty

>>> new_dfr['ADDRESS'].isna()

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
Name: ADDRESS, dtype: bool

>>> ~new_dfr['ADDRESS'].astype(bool)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
Name: ADDRESS, dtype: bool

>>> new_dfr['ADDRESS'].isna() | ~new_dfr['ADDRESS'].astype(bool)

0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
Name: ADDRESS, dtype: bool

>>> (new_dfr['ADDRESS'].isna() | ~new_dfr['ADDRESS'].astype(bool)).sum()
5
```