# Calculate mean of coordinates of a Pandas Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas Series like this, name `place`:

```
0    [[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]]]
1    [[[3,2], [6,4], [7,6], [2,8]]]
2    nan
...
```

the elements of each row are the coordinates of the vertices of a box.

I would like to find the center of the box, keeping the `nan` values as I want to concatenate this series to a dataframe and I need the same number of rows.

My initial idea was to write a function to calculate the mean:

```
def centroid(arr_val):
    if arr_val:
        center = np.mean(np.array(arr_val[0]), axis=0)
    else:
        center = arr_val
    return center
```

and apply it to each element of the series:

```
place.apply(lambda x: centroid(x))
```

but I have some problem with the dimention of the list in the series as it's a list of list of lists...

What I would like to have is:

```
0   [4., 5.]
1   [4.5, 5. ]
2   nan
...
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not the dimensions of the lists, it is that you are not properly checking whether the input is `nan` or not. Your test passes even when `arr_val` is `nan`:

```py
arr_val = np.nan
if arr_val:
    print('nan is truthy')
```

Prints `nan is truthy`. See [Why do "Not a Number" values equal True when cast as boolean in Python/Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15686318/9473764)

Changing your test - given your data it's probably simplest just to check for a list - will resolve your problem:

```py
def centroid(arr_val):
    if isinstance(arr_val, list):
        center = np.mean(np.array(arr_val[0]), axis=0)
    else:
        center = arr_val
    return center

place = pd.Series([
    [[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]]],
    [[[3,2], [6,4], [7,6], [2,8]]],
    np.nan
])
place.apply(centroid)
```

Output:

```
0    [4.0, 5.0]
1    [4.5, 5.0]
2           NaN
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can build [`Polygon`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.Polygon.html)s (*if any*) then compute the [`centroid`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.centroid.html) provided by [geopandas](/questions/tagged/geopandas) :

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

ser = place.str[0].dropna().apply(Polygon)

out = (gpd.GeoSeries(ser).centroid
           .apply(lambda p: list(map(
        lambda v: round(v, 1), (p.x, p.y)))) # optional ?
           .reindex_like(place)
      )
```

A variant with pure [shapely](/questions/tagged/shapely)', using its [`centroid`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.centroid) :

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

out = (place.str[0].dropna().apply(
    lambda x: [round(Polygon(x).centroid.x, 1),
               round(Polygon(x).centroid.y, 1)])
           .reindex_like(place)
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

0    [4.0, 5.0]
1    [4.2, 5.2]
2           NaN
Length: 3, dtype: object
```

Used input :

```
place = pd.Series([
    [[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]],
    [[[3, 2], [6, 4], [7, 6], [2, 8]]],
    pd.NA
    ]
)
```

Comment: Note this doesn't match OPs desired result

Comment: Yes, don't worry, I'm ready to adjust and/or delete it if necessary ;)